# result table is showing blank after operating union operation between 3 nonempty rdd frame in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am  new in spark and facing a weird problem . I have three RDD data frame t1frame, t2frame, t3frame  and all these are non empty the pictures are given

t1frame
bellow[image]

t2frame
[image]

t3frame
[image]

i have used  bellow code first i have imported reduce and dataframe

```
def unionAll(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,dfs)



TTunified=unionAll(t1frame,t2frame,t3frame)
TTunified.show()
```

[image]

i have got this blank table. then i have tried unifying tow dataframe

```
unionframe1=t1frame.union(t2frame)
unionframe1.show()
```

and i have got the same result. even i have tried table based approach as well  but nothing changed. how could i solve it kindly guide me . am i missing something  here. i am using pyspark 2.0